# Finding multiple records through has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Customer and Person models looks like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer
end
```

How can I get all Person records that have an association with a Customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with sql it might be something like

```
 Customer.where("customers.person_id IS NOT NULL")
```

to get `Person` record you can use `join`

```
 Person.joins( :customers ).where("customers.person_id IS NOT NULL")
```

I'm not sue either `where` is necessary here (I believe no) so try `Person.joins( :customers )` first

Comment: I thought about something similar at first, but that way you get all Customer records, not all Person ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
person_array = []
Person.all.each do |p|
  unless p.customer.nil?
    person_array << p
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, Bohdan's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the fastest query but:

```
Customer.where('person_id IS NOT NULL').map(&:person)
```

Answer (score 0):

rails 2.3.x

```
Customer.all(:include => :person).map(&:person).compact
```